# Android problems with onClick()

Tags: java, android

**Thank you all, I managed! I had to put in a switch ((Button) v)**

I'm quite new in coding  and can't understand why  doesn't work my code.
I want to combine all three buttons under one method `onClick()` and android studio shows me that everything is written without errors, but when I run the application, it instantly closes.

```
package com.example.trafficlight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
final Button LightSide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LightSide);
final Button DarkSide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DarkSide);
final Button Chubaka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Chubaka);
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    LightSide.setOnClickListener(this);
    DarkSide.setOnClickListener(this);
    Chubaka.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.LightSide:
            LightSide.setText("LightSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        case R.id.DarkSide:
            DarkSide.setText("DarkSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        case R.id.Chubaka:
            Chubaka.setText("Chubakka");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));

    }

}
}
```

This is Bug Code
    05-16 12:43:06.874 8223-8223/com.example.trafficlight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.trafficlight, PID: 8223
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.trafficlight.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: ok, initialize all Buttons's inside onCreate method after calling `setContentView `

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to move your `findViewById` calls into the onCreate method :

```
Button mLightSide;
Button mDarkSide;
Button mChubaka;
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    mLightSide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LightSide);
    mDarkSide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DarkSide);
    mChubaka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Chubaka);
    mLightSide.setOnClickListener(this);
    mDarkSide.setOnClickListener(this);
    mChubaka.setOnClickListener(this);


}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the app opens, but when I try to click on one of the buttons again crashes) The Text is "unfortunately,trafficlight has stopped'

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for people to help you if you were posting whatever crash you're getting in the logcat right?

Comment: U can see that in my post)

Answer (score 0):

try this

Intialise all button in OnCreate Method.
insert `break;` after each case

```
case R.id.LightSide:
            LightSide.setText("LightSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
break;
        case R.id.DarkSide:
            DarkSide.setText("DarkSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
break;
        case R.id.Chubaka:
            Chubaka.setText("Chubakka");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit complex in the mechanism. I guess you've linked the click event in xml file where one of your button's click event has been set(onClick="onClick") because the argument of onclick is View, in this case, the method will only work with the button that has been linked, for the other button.

the short answer is: give every button widget an unique ID, and implements their OnClickListner;

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new function to the onClick event of all the buttons and don't override the Activity one. Also, insert break; after each case like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    LightSide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonOnClick(v);
        }
    });
    DarkSide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonOnClick(v);
        }
    });
    Chubaka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonOnClick(v);
        }
    });
}

private void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.LightSide:
            LightSide.setText("LightSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            break;
        case R.id.DarkSide:
            DarkSide.setText("DarkSide");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            break;
        case R.id.Chubaka:
            Chubaka.setText("Chubakka");
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
            break;
    }
}
```

EDITED:
Also put the findViewById methods like NSimon said on his/her answer.